# Transaction rollback and save info

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, mariadb, spring-transactions

In the service layer, I have some method who have a transactional annotation.

```
@Transactional
public void process() throws ProcessPaymentException{ 
    try{
    .... do some operation
    catch (ProcessPaymentException ppe) {
        save db problem issue.
    }
}
```

It seem like if there are a issue, there are roll back... and nothing is saved in the db...

ProcessPaymentException extend Exception

Is there a way to rollback the  process in the try but do the save in the catch?

Edit

Nested transaction could be a solution if this link is ok
https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/java/common-oversights-utilizing-nested-transactions-spring/

Comment: you should override default rollback implementation. **@Transactional** has ann attribute named **rollbackfor** , you can try to implement a new one there. Oher option should be with aspects, implementing a exception aspect.

Answer (score 1):

Existing answer of using `ControllerAdvise` should help in normal setup that incoming requests are coming through Spring MVC (i.e. through a `Controller`).

For cases that is not, or you do not want to tie your exception handling logic to Spring MVC, here are some alternatives I can think of

(Here I assume you want to rely on declarative transaction control instead of programmatically controlling transactions yourself)

1. Separate service/component to save error in different transaction.

   In short, you can have a separate service, which create its own transaction by propagation `REQUIRES_NEW`.  e.g.

   ```
   @Service
   public class FooService
       @Inject
       private ErrorAuditService errorAuditService;

       @Transactional
       public void process() throws ProcessPaymentException{ 
           try{
           .... do some operation
           catch (ProcessPaymentException ppe) {
               errorAuditService.saveErrorAudit(ppe.getErrorText());
               throw ppe;  // I guess you want to re-throw the exception
           }
       }
   }


   @Service
   public class ErrorAuditService
       @Transactional(propagation=REQUIRES_NEW)
       public void saveErrorAudit() { 
           // save to DB
       }
   }
   ```
2. One step further, if the error handling it the same for different services, you may create an advise, which will be called when service method throws exception.  In that advise, you can save the error in db (using `ErrorAuditService`), and rethrow the exception.

Comment: Another option is to use self-reference, i.e. use the same service. In such case you just inject `FooService` into itself (via `@Autowired @Lazy private FooService selfReference;`) and then you can apply `REQUIRES_NEW` to the local method, finally call this method through injected self-reference: `selfReference.saveErrorAudit()` - whenever you need it in a nested transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Because processes of try-catch are wrapped by the same transaction.
The transaction manager do rollback whenever an exception is thrown. So, not thing would be saved.

> Is there a way to rollback the process in the try but do the save in the catch?

Yes. Create Exception Handler to save db problem issue after rollback.
this is the idea

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class HandlerName {
    @ExceptionHandler(ProcessPaymentException.class)
    public void saveDbIssue(ProcessPaymentException ex) {
        // save db problem issue.
}
```

But it only works if u want to save static data.

Comment: not possible to pass a string to this method or list of string?

Comment: You can pass a string to ProcessPaymentException's constructor, then git it as **saveDbIssue** method parameter.

Comment: I believe `ControllerAdvice` is for exception handler of `Controller`s only.  i.e. if the incoming request for OP's service is not coming through a `Controller`, this approach won't work.